# Does NodeJS support "Import" style module loading?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I am looking at a NodeJS project, which is downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/amirrajan/word-finder). It has a main file, `server.js`, which uses the ES6 module import syntax like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import fs from 'fs';
import { search } from './lib/words';
```

I have NodeJS version 4.6.0 installed, which is pretty old, and I do not think it supports this syntax. Instead, it should be like:

```
var express = require(express)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
...
```

However I can run this project correctly without error, which I think shows that NodeJS supports this syntax, but the NodeJS documentation never specifies such module syntax. What is the reason we can use it here? Thank you for help.

Comment: It doesn't support it on its own.  Some folks use Babel to work around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `npm start`, the [start script in the `package.json`](https://github.com/amirrajan/word-finder/blob/master/package.json#L7) is run, meaning that [`start.js`](https://github.com/amirrajan/word-finder/blob/master/start.js) gets executed.

`start.js` uses [`babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) to transpile the new ES6 syntax (including the imports) to plain ES5 JavaScript that Node understands on the fly. The [`.babelrc`](https://github.com/amirrajan/word-finder/blob/master/.babelrc) shows that the [`es2015` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) is being used, which converts ES2015 (ES6) code to normal ES5 JS.

The particular transformer that matters to you is [`transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/), which will transform `import` to `require` as expected.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.

Comment: Sadly, the github repo you are referring to is gone. But I think [this post](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/) pretty much has the same explanation…